# How to refactor a DOM traverser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently read through Clean Code by Robert Martin, and I'm trying to implement some of the principles of good code, in particular the principle of "don't repeat yourself", or "DRY". I'm writing a walker that can move forwards or backwards inside the DOM of an HTML document, assuming the elements are ordered by depth-first search.

Staring at my code I can't shake the feeling that I'm repeating much of the logic, yet for the life of me I can't think of any specific refactoring strategy. I know it's only ~50 lines of code, and I should probably just use it and get on with my life. But still, I'm extremely curious if there's a better approach, if only for academic reasons.

How would I go about making this code cleaner? Any ideas?

```
//returns previous element in a depth-first search traversal
//returns null if at the start of the tree
TreeWalker.prototype.getPreviousElement = function(element) {
  var previousElement;
  if(element.previousElementSibling === null) {
    var parent = element.parentElement;
    if($(parent).is(this.rootSelector)) {
      previousElement = null;
    } else {
      previousElement = parent;
    }
  } else {
    var beforeBranch = element.previousElementSibling;
    previousElement = this.cycleToPreviousBranch(beforeBranch);
  }
  return previousElement;
};


TreeWalker.prototype.cycleToPreviousBranch = function(element) {
  var previousElement;
  if(element.children.length === 0) {
    previousElement = element;
  } else {
    var lastChild = element.lastElementChild;
    previousElement = this.cycleToPreviousBranch(lastChild);
  }
  return previousElement;
};

//returns next element in a depth-first search traversal
//returns null if at the end of the tree
TreeWalker.prototype.getNextElement = function(element) {
  var nextElement;
  if(element.children.length > 0) {
    nextElement = element.children[0];
  } else {
    nextElement = this.cycleToNextBranch(element);
  }
  return nextElement;
};

TreeWalker.prototype.cycleToNextBranch = function(element) {
  var nextElement;
  if(element.nextElementSibling !== null) {
    nextElement = element.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    var parent = element.parentElement;
    if($(parent).is(this.rootSelector)) {
      nextElement = null;
    } else {
      nextElement = this.cycleToNextBranch(parent);
    }
  }
  return nextElement;
};
```

Comment: If this is working code and you are just looking for improvements, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably the place for you to post.

Comment: Also, you will need to make sure the purpose of each function is clearly described and describe why if you have jQuery, you aren't using jQuery for anything other than selector comparison?